# Is there a way for a Telegram bot to get its own messages that it has sent in a private channel where it is an admin?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I just want a way to get the messages that my Telegram bot has posted in a private channel where it is an admin. I found this question from over 3 years ago:

[Is there any way to get all messages that a Telegram Bot has sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953685/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-messages-that-a-telegram-bot-has-sent)

They say it wasn't possible at the time. I'm wondering if it is possible now.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's still not possible. The only way to get old messages is to use the [Telegram client APIs](https://core.telegram.org/api). With these APIs you can do everything a normal user can do (including obtaining the chat history).

Another method is to save the messages the bot send to the channel in a database or in a file for future use, but obviously you won't be able to get the messages you didn't save.